# Is it possible to use MyServices.ClipboardProxy in VBA?

Tags: vba

Is there a way to access the [`ClipboardProxy` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.myservices.clipboardproxy?view=netframework-4.8) from VBA?

Many classes can be instantiated via `CreateObject`, e.g.:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set obj = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
' etc.
```

I'm unable to figure out what the appropriate *ClassName* would be, or whether any DLL reference(s) need to be added in order to use this class in VBA.

**NOTE**: I'm aware of how to instantiate a `DataObject`, but this is not the same thing. (Related: The `ClipboardProxy.GetDataObject` returns a `DataObject`. But I'm looking specifically for the `ClipboardProxy` class, not the `IDataObject`).

Comment: Does the [`MSForms.DataObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copy-getfromclipboard-gettext-methods-dataobject-object-example) not work for your needs?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs thanks, but unfortunately no. I just added a note to that effect based on the answer Vitaya posted a few minutes ago.